# How can I include packages(folders) in the compilation of a java project through terminal?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

So, I want to compile a java benchmark.

I am working inside the folder /home/username/Tools/myTool/folder2.
I am compiling with `javac -cp /home/username/Tools/appv1.0/ *.java`

folder1 compile sucesfully because it did not have any dependencies on packages.

Right inside folder 2, that I have the problem, there are 5 folders residing as packages(having some java classes), but the compiler can not recognize them, so I need to put that explicitly.

And I keep getting errors like this

`JClass1.java:22: error: package crypt does not exist
import crypt.*;
^
JClass2.java:23: error: package series does not exist
import series.*; 
^`

So, how can I direct the compiler towards those packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am giving absolute paths.

Comment: Add the folder where you have other packages to classpath, java must know the location of all dependent necessary class files ( jars or class files)

Comment: try using only javac -cp /home/username/Tools/appv1.0/* and not *.java

Comment: @user1933888 how can I do that? give me the command please.

Comment: javac -cp jar1:jar2:jar3:dir1:. *.java

Comment: javac -cp dir1/*:dir2/* MainClass.java

Comment: @yogx Thank you very much!!! and the user1933888 as well!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must write the command to compile as:

```
javac -d bin -sourcepath src -cp lib/lib1.jar;lib/lib2.jar src/com/example/YOUR_FILE_NAME.java
```

As a result bin/com/example/Application.class file should be created. If Application.java uses other classes from the project, they all should be automatically compiled and put into corresponding folders.

For more [info](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/).

Answer (score 0):

The anwser provided by yogx was the right one after all!!

Problem solved.

`javac -cp dir1/*:dir2/* MainClass.java`

Thank you all!